# aws iam role move from CloudFormation to CDK

Tags: python, amazon-iam, aws-cdk

I am trying to move this iam role from CloudFormation to AWS CDK. I cant seem to find any good examples of this in Python. The Condition is where I am stuck at the moment. Has anyone created a role similar to this in Python?

```
  CognitoUnAuthorizedRole:
    Type: "AWS::IAM::Role"
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument: 
        Version: "2012-10-17"
        Statement:
          - Effect: "Allow"
            Principal: 
              Federated: "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com"
            Action: 
              - "sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity"
            Condition:
              StringEquals: 
                "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:aud": !Ref IdentityPool
              "ForAnyValue:StringLike":
                "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:amr": unauthenticated
      Policies:
        - PolicyName: "CognitoAuthorizedPolicy"
          PolicyDocument: 
            Version: "2012-10-17"
            Statement: 
              - Effect: "Allow"
                Action:
                  - "cognito-sync:*"
                Resource: !Join [ "", [ "arn:aws:cognito-sync:", !Ref "AWS::Region", ":", !Ref "AWS::AccountId", ":identitypool/", !Ref IdentityPool] ]
              - Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - iot:Connect
                Resource: !Join [ "", [ "arn:aws:iot:", !Ref "AWS::Region", ":", !Ref "AWS::AccountId", ":client/theme*" ] ]
              - Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - iot:Subscribe
                Resource: "*"
              - Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - iot:Receive
                Resource: !Join [ "", [ "arn:aws:iot:", !Ref "AWS::Region", ":", !Ref "AWS::AccountId", ":topic/*" ] ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You should search the method in the lib, eg.

```
auth_role = aws_iam.Role(
        self,
        'ApiGwAuthRole',
        assumed_by=aws_iam.ServicePrincipal("apigateway.amazonaws.com")
)
```

Add policy to a resource

```
_sqs.add_to_resource_policy(
        statement=aws_iam.PolicyStatement(
            effect=aws_iam.Effect.ALLOW,
            actions=['sqs:SendMessage'],
            resources=[_sqs.queue_arn],
            principals=[aws_iam.AnyPrincipal()],
            conditions={
                "ArnEquals": {"aws:SourceArn": _source.ref}
            }
        )
    )
```